# Conservation of angular momentum in the H atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

So, my proff. says that when an electron in the $1s$ orbital of the H-atom is given an energy, it can rise to the $2s$ orbital state. This is all good, but the question that I want to ask is, if an electron in the $2s$ state is given some energy, can it rise to the $2p$ state? The reason I am asking is because energy conservation is obviously taken care of by
$$\hbar\omega=E_{2p}-E_{2s}$$
But, is conservation of angular momentum taken care of? Since the value of the orbital angular momentum quantum number $l$ would have to shift from $l=0$ to $l=1$. This, I am guessing, would cause a shift in the angular momentum of the electron and the conservation of angular momentum would be lost. So, is the transition from the $2s$ to the $2p$ orbital not possible? Or how does this transition take place? Because, as far as I know, photons would have a momentum equivalent to $p=\hbar\omega/c$, but do they have angular momentum? I mean, I'm sorry to sound like a noob, but I am an engineer who's studying physics, so maybe I am just looking at things differently. Do the laws of conservation of momentum not hold at all at these levels?

Comment: Photon does have angular momentum: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light .

Answer (score 3):

Angular momentum, as you correctly note, must be conserved. An emitted or absorbed particle will take care of the unaccounted angular momentum. And because of this condition, [selection rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule#Angular_momentum) apply, allowing only certain transitions, or making some [extremely unlikely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbidden_mechanism) and only driven by different interaction mechanisms.

From the Wikipedia page I linked:

> The emitted particle carries away an angular momentum λ, which for the photon must be at least 1, since it is a vector particle.

Other details and calculations can be found there.